Paragraph translations - an additional twist
As per https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/paragraphs/multilingual-paragraphs-configuration:

I have a node bundle with a paragraphs field. The paragraphs field is NOT set for translation.

In config/regional/content-language I selected Paragraph, and down below in the list of paragraph types I selected Alert and enabled its message (text) field for translation.

Under manage fields for the Alert paragraph type, the message field is set to allow users to translate.

There is an existing piece of content with two alerts. If I switch from English to Spanish, the alerts appear in Spanish.

If I edit the Spanish translation of the content and edit either of the alert paragraphs, the alert message shows as English...? (the new twist). Cannot find any sign of the Spanish versions. This is acting like the reverse of orphans. The content appears on the page, but when editing the node it is not shown among the paragraphs.

If I add a new paragraph in the English translation (default language, source content), then go into the Spanish translation and translate the text and save, the translation appears when selecting the English or Spanish page, both.


The same behavior in #6 happens when creating new content. If I edit and save the paragraph text in the Spanish translation, that translation appears universally. If I then do the same with the English version, the English appears universally.

If I switch from English to Spanish, the alerts appear in Spanish. How were the Alerts originally translated then if not by the new steps you followed?  You could just try deleting the paragraph and recreating them if new paragraphs are translating ok

New paragraphs are not translating ok (see #6).
I was not involved with the site when the node that displays Spanish that cannot be found on any edit screen was created ... 5 years ago.
